# How to handle a failed write behind from the GridCacheWriteBehindStore?

Tags: ignite

`GridCacheWriteBehindStore` does not log the object type or its fields when a write to the underlying store fails. We accept that the cache and the underlying store may be out of sync when using write behind, but we NEED to know what failed.

A simple, and likely example is when there is a NOT NULL constraint on a field in a database table and no such check exists in the java layer.

Here is all you see ... Note also that it's only log level warn which also seems wrong.

> [WARN ] 2016-11-30 14:23:17.178 [flusher-0-#57%null%]
>   GridCacheWriteBehindStore - Unable to update underlying store:
>   o.a.i.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore@3a60c416

Answer (score 2):

You're right, exception is ignored there. This will be fixed in the upcoming 1.8: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3770